# How to make Flex AIR auto generate an Integer in a text box with the coordination of number of JSON files?

Tags: json, apache-flex, air, primary-key

What I wanted to happen,

1. When a form pops-up, the text box would automatically generate an Integer, 
   regarding of the total number of JSON files located in my documentsdirectory +1.
2. The text box would be the file name of my JSON file and be saved in documentsdirectory.
3. After clicking save, form closes and save.
4. Repeats step 1.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Post your code, and someone might be able to help.  As it stands, the answer to your question is "By writing some Flex code."  Sorry if that seems snarky, but your question seems like a request to have people write your code for you.

Comment: ... based on your other questions, I don't think that's what you mean to do, but even so, this question is currently way too broad.

Comment: Is that your homework?

Comment: Sorry guys, I just wanted to know is it possible to generate a primary key in flex? If yes, can you show some?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can count the number of JSON files using something like the function below that iterates through a directory and looks for files with extension "json".

```
private function countJsonFiles(dir:File):int
{
    var numJsonFiles = 0;
    //iterate through directory and make entries for assets
    for each(var file:File in dir.getDirectoryListing())
    {

        if (!file.isDirectory)
        {
                //the last condition assumes you only want to count files with extension "json"
                //I'm not sure if you want to count all the files or a different extension,
                //so you can modify that part as needed
                if (file.name != "." && file.name != ".." && file.extension == "json")
                {
                    numJsonFiles++;
                }

        }
        return numJsonFiles;
    }
}
```

Then you can write to a new JSON file with its name concatenated with the number of JSON files so far plus 1:

```
var file:File = File.documentsDirectory.resolvePath("jsonFile" + countJsonFiles(File.documentsDirectory) + 1 + ".json");
var stream:FileStream = new FileStream();
stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
stream.writeUTFBytes(text_box.text);
stream.close();
```

A more elegant solution to this would be to use an AIR SQLite database. You can find all the info you need here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a5497-7fb4.html

Basically you can create a simple table that has just one column "numJSONFiles" and increment this whenever a new file is created. That way, you always remember what the last index was that you used for a json file.

I don't recommend using EncryptedLocalStore here as it's not really sensitive information and doesn't quite fit the criteria found here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/data/EncryptedLocalStore.html

Hope this helps!

Comment: can you please show me also how to use encryptedlocalstore that stores integer that also auto increment after a JSON file is created with the filename of the incremented value? It is because when I tested my code, I got a problem in the delete part. Example: I already have the 5th json file, and then I will delete it, after that, when I create it become back to 5. But the filename should be unique :) its like a primary key :) Thanks in advance

Comment: I updated my answer to say that you could use an SQLite database to store the number of json files you've indexed so far. Reading the documentation on EncryptedLocalStore, I don't see this is as a viable solution for this particular problem statement.

Comment: Thanks it really helped me a lot. My self project got stuck due to this situation :) . I am sorry for the noob questions still learning in flex.